# Django server does not start, the site does not work when starting dockerfile

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm training in the dockerfile assembly, I can't understand why it doesn't work.
Python django project GitHub:
[https://github.com/BrianRuizy/covid19-dashboard][1]

At the moment I have such a dockerfile, who knows how to create docker files, help me figure it out and tell me what my mistake is.

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ADD requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "127.0.0.1:8000"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You never coppied your files to the container an example would look like something like this. This also prevents as running as superuser

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

#INSTALL REQUIREMENTS
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install default-libmysqlclient-dev gcc wget

# create the app user
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash app && mkdir /app && chown -R app:app /app

# copy the requirements
COPY  --chown=app:app ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
COPY  --chown=app:app ./deploy-requirements.txt /app/deploy-requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
# and install them
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt && pip install -r deploy-requirements.txt

#####
#
# everything below runs as the 'app' user for security reasons
#
#####

USER app
#COPY APP
COPY --chown=app:app . /app
WORKDIR /app

#RUN
ENTRYPOINT gunicorn -u app -g app --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 PROJECT.asgi:application -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
```